# becomeFirstResponder slows down app

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have two textfields for username and password and a submit button. When the submit button is pressed a check is performed to see if the username and password was typed or not. If not it shows an alert message and the field whose value was not entered becomes the first responder.

```
-(IBAction)loginPressed:(id)sender {


    if ([username.text length] == 0)
    {
        [self showAlert:@"Invalid Username/ Password"];
       [username becomeFirstResponder];
        return;
    }

    if ([password.text length] == 0)
    {
        [self showAlert:@"Invalid Username/ Password"];
      [password becomeFirstResponder];
        return;
    }
}
```

I observed that on clicking the button, the button remains selected for about 1.5 seconds and then the alert is shown. If I comment out the `becomeFirstResponder` method, it works without any pause. However I need `becomeFirstResponder` to be there. How do I speed things up using this?

Comment: Possibly stupid question: What happens if you switch the ordering of becomeFirstResponder and showAlert?

Comment: Hey that solved it. Works nicely now. Thanks. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch the ordering of becomeFirstResponder and showAlert.

Comment: I have the same problem with no alert :(. Massive delay (several seconds!) to call becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: I'm having the same issue too, with no alert - just unhiding a view/textfield, and then calling becomeFirstResponder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[self showAlert:@"Invalid Username/ Password"]; will take a time. you cant speeup that thing.

Comment: But according to the OP, there is no delay if the becomeFirstResponder is removed, so apparently, showAlert is not the issue here.